# Standard deviation & approximate distribution of sample mean given population mean and standard deviation.

Tags: statistics, means

I have the population mean and standard distribution.

I am asked to find the standard deviation from a sample population of 96, and the approximate distribution of the sample mean.

I don't have the original data, and they've used slightly different language in the question to the learning material.

Which equations are appropriate?

Comment: What do you mean by standard distribution?

Comment: The standard deviation of the whole population.
The population has a normal distribution.

Comment: Do you know the standard deviation of the population ?

Comment: Yes. I  have the SD and mean of the whole population.

Comment: The sample mean is distributed as $\large{\overline X\sim \mathcal N\left(\mu, \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{96}} \right)}$. This is the exact distribution.